# Приглашение ввода печатается после ввода Haskell

Tags: ввод, haskell

При выполнении следующего кода не происходит вывода приглашения к вводу перед непосредственно вводом (что ожидается).
Программа сначала ждёт ввод, а только после него выводит приглашение и строку с использованием введённого имени. Что я делаю не так?

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Please enter your name:"
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ name ++ ", how are you?")
```

**Вывод:**

```
5
Please enter your name:
Hello, 5, how are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

Это просто буферизация консоли так работает. По умолчанию консоль накапливает вывод пока не случится что-нибудь неординарное - например ввод или достаточно много вывода накопится, - и тогда печатает всё, что накопилось. По моему опыту это так работает только в Windows, и я думаю, что это баг.

Но это легко починить: вы можете явно указать, чтобы буфер копился только до ближайшего перевода строки. Чтобы это сделать, воспользуйтесь [функцией `hSetBuffering`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.13/base-4.14.3.0/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering):

```
import System.IO (BufferMode (LineBuffering), hSetBuffering)

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
  ...
```